# What is the difference between 'in a long time' and 'for a long time'?

Tags: meaning

There are two sentences below

1. I have played soccer for a long time.
2. I have played soccer in a long time.

What is the difference between the two sentences above in meaning?
Please, tell me.

Answer (score 4):

I was about to upvote Tromano's answer when I noticed that the OP's examples are *both* in the positive form. If they had been in the **negative**:

> 1. I have**n't** played soccer **for** a long time.
> 2. I have**n't** played soccer **in** a long time.

There would be no difference in meaning. If both sentences had been in the *Past Simple*, there would be no difference in meaning

> 1. That **was** the best restaurant I've been to **for/in a long time** (= a long period has gone past since I went to such a good restaurant).

But the OP's sentences are in the *Present Perfect* tense, and only the first one is idiomatic. The second is not.

> 1. I ***have played*** soccer **for** a long time. (RIGHT)
> 2. I ***have played*** soccer **in** a long time. (WRONG)

The Present Perfect is often used to express a duration of time, an action that began in the past and continues to the present time. To say how long something has continued we use **for**, to say when the action began we use **since**.

> 1. I have played soccer **for** twenty years (=I have played this sport for a total of 20 years)
> 2. I have played soccer **since** 1998 (=I started playing the sport in 1998 and I have not stopped playing)

Cambridge dictionaries defines this meaning of *time* as

> ### [time](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/time)
>
> noun (PERIOD)  a particular period of time for which something has been happening, or that is needed for something
>
> - **After a time**, it became clear that nobody was interested in coming to the meetings.
> - They stayed with us **for a short** time.
> - That was the best restaurant I've been to **for/in a long** time (= a long period has gone past since I went to such a good restaurant).
> - It was **some** time **ago** that I last heard from her.
> - We're going on holiday **in two weeks'** time

Comment: "That was the best restaurant I've been to for/in a long time" - I'd argue that "for" would be incorrect here, and "in" would be correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you began with soccer as a small child, and now you are  in your thirties, you could say *I have played soccer for a long time*.

If you injured your ankle and required surgery, and then your recuperation lasted a year, during which time you were walking with crutches, you could say *I have not played soccer in a long time.*

Comment: Just my guess ))) : first, _I have not played soccer **for** a long time_ is also possible for the situation, isn't it? second, there is a lack of a quantifier in your example, imo, thereby it sounds a bit stilted (?). Wouldn't _I have not played soccer **once** in a long time_ be better?

Comment: You should not infer from my answer that the negative was impossible with **for** merely because I did not list it there.

Comment: @Mv Log: I cannot recall whether you're a native speaker or not. But *I haven't played soccer in a long time* is not at all stilted.  It is perfectly idiomatic. Your suggestion "I have not played soccer once in a long time" is borderline idiomatic. You'd want to say **even once** or **--not even once--**   *I have not played soccer -- not even once -- in a very long time*.  But that wouldn't suit the scenario I presented, where the man is on crutches.  Would you expect him to have tried to play?   And neither addition, **even once**, or **--not even once--**, is needed.

Comment: *I haven't been to London once in a long time* is not  really idiomatic.

Comment: No, I'm not ))) that's why I've got sometimes rather weird impressions of locutions which are fully idiomatic for a native speaker. I agree that **even once** is much bettter than just **once**. Perhaps, that's what is meant in your example, sort of omission\ellipsis = _I have not played soccer (even once) in a long time_ ? And sure, that might be said after the completion of the recuperation, not standing on the crutches. As regards London, what about such a variant: _Not once I've been to London in a long time (so everything here seems unfamiliar to me now.)_?

Comment: @Mv Log: There's no ellipsis in *I haven't played soccer in a long time*.  The present perfect in conjunction with the prepositional phrase "in a long time" is understood to mean *from some (unspecified but distant) point in the past, up until this moment, there has been no soccer playing by me.*  That's a wooden paraphrase, just trying to get at the underlying ideas.

Comment: @Mv Log: "Not once I've been" is not grammatical. When beginning with "Not once" there is subject-verb inversion. *Not once **have I** been to London*  That inverted form adds great emphasis, as one might need when denying such a statement.  *Sergeant, not once have I been to London this past year!  I cannot have been Sir Reginald's murderer.*

Comment: While "in a long time" and "for a long time" are interchangeable, addition of "even once" seems to ruin that balance: we can say  _I have not played soccer even once in a long time_ but can we say  _I have not played soccer even once for a long time_ as well? As for the inversion - my fault, thanks )))

Comment: The pleonasm of *I have not played soccer even once for a long time* creates some cognitive dissonance for me.   One would expect  a **since**-clause with **even once**:  *...even once since my biking accident.*   **for a long time** expresses the *duration* of the predicated action or state, and **even once** expresses *instance* of the predicated action.

Comment: Agreed. I think there is more to it than just cognitive dissonance—we say "once in a while" but not "once for a while", don't we?

Comment: Departures from set phrases like "once in a while" are starker.